# How do I memorize algorithms?

Tags: java

I am an AP Computer Science student and I need help memorizing the algorithms.The algorithms are in a revision sheet and they are about abstract classes, interfaces, and polymorphism, so what would be the easiest way to memorize this.Thanks!

Comment: Understand them. Or alternatively, go write some applications with Java. Eventually your brain will refuse to open the books and memorize them.

Comment: Also... this is off-topic for stackoverflow. Consider academia (I'm not familiar with other SE sites so I'm not sure, be sure to read their How to ask page first).

Comment: Thanks will try and hope i get that 100

Answer (score 2):

Try to understand and learn them.Never try to memorize as you'll sooner forget them

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest don't try to memorize them instead understand the concepts and logics used in any algorithm